# Why do we need to know שעשגז's name?

Tags: names, megillat-esther

Why does מגילת אסתר make a point of telling us that the סריס המלך שומר הפילגשים was called שעשגז?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [Medrash Lekach Tov](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Midrash_Lekach_Tov_on_Esther.2.14?vhe=Sifre_DeAgadeta,_Vilna_1886&lang=he) explains that by naming both הֵגַי and שַׁעֲשְׁגַז  it highlights the fact that there were 2  seperate"*harems*".

הֵגַי was in charge of those getting ready to meet the king, and he was a שֹׁמֵר הַנָּשִׁים.

שַׁעֲשְׁגַז was in charge of those who already met the King, and he was a שֹׁמֵר הַפִּילַגְשִׁים.

By naming them we don't make the mistake of assuming that the שֹׁמֵר הַנָּשִׁים and the שֹׁמֵר הַפִּילַגְשִׁים were the same person even though both their *harems* were named בֵּית הַנָּשִׁים.

> בערב היא באה. למדנו צניעות המלך שלא שימש מטתו ביום, שנאמר ובבקר היא שבה אל בית הנשים, לא אל בית הנשים אל יד הגא אלא על ידי שעשגז סריס המלך שומר הפלגשים, למעלה אמר אל יד הגא שומר הנשים, וכאן כתיב שומר הפילגשים, ללמדך שבתחלה ניתנו ע"י הגא, וכאשר באות אל המלך מקץ י"ב חודש, אם חפץ בה המלך היה נותן כתר מלכות בראשה, ואם לאו היתה ניתנת על יד שעשגז, והיתה נקראת מן הפלגשים, שהרי בא המלך אליהן, לא תבוא עוד אל המלך, כי אם חפץ בה המלך ונקראה בשם, אבל פלגש היתה נקראת:‏